# Start a systemd service after specific check returns RC 0

Tags: systemd, services, reboot

On a boot of a system with systemd there is a service which starts successfully. After a while that service applies a certain configuration to the system.

**Once** that configuration is applied, I'd like to start another service, e.g. crond. There is a command to verify whether the configuration applied. Once that command returns a return code of 0, then the other service, crond, must start.

Example command:

`grep something file.txt` # this could be a check. If 'something' is in the file.txt, it returns a RC 0.

I cannot use `After=` or `Before=`, due to the fact the configuration is applied after the starting of the service. This is not instant, and may take up to 30s.

**Q:** How would I configure a systemd service to start after a certain check has a return code of 0?

Comment: Do you have much control over the configuring service?  If so, you could use [`Type=notify`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=) for the service and call [`systemd-notify`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-notify.html) from the shell or [`sd_notify`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html#) from C when the configuration is actually complete.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `foo` makes the configuration which `bar` uses.

`foo.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Configuration Service
Before=bar.service

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/path/to/script
```

Then `/path/to/script` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/locan/bin/do_configuration.sh

# Make sure the configuration is actually valid
if grep -q something file.txt; then

# send a signal to systemd that the unit is good. 
  systemd-notify --ready

# systemd will continue to launch dependent services
  exit 0

else
  systemd-notify ERRNO=2
  exit 1
fi
```

I think it's worth playing around with this a little.  A `RequiredBy=` or `WantedBy=` dependency may also be necessary.

---

Another option is using this in `ExecStartPre=` of `bar.service`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
   if grep -q something file.txt
   then
    break
   fi
done
```

But I don't like this option because:

1. It's constantly unnecessarily polling
2. If you try `systemctl start bar`, systemctl will hang until the condition is met

Answer (score 0):

You can use a systemd service combining `Before`, `ExecStart` and restart options (using `RestartSec` to avoid to many attempts).

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo
Before=the other service

[Service]
ExecStart=grep -q something file.txt
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s
```

But it's probably better to have your configuration system to trigger the next service instead of polling/grepping a file.